# read_html but run javascript content?

Tags: r, rvest

When using `read_html()` on a webpage, it it returns:

> Please enable scripts for this website.

And none of the other page content loads.

Is there any way to run scripts when using `rvest`? (perhaps using [V8](https://github.com/jeroen/V8#v8), or some otherway), or is the only way to go all-out with [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium#rselenium)?